# How can I make Shift-Ctrl act as alt-gr (right-alt) in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard

I would like to be able to hit shift-ctrl instead of alt-gr (right alt) on my wireless apple keyboard in Ubuntu. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> isn't supported as an option for that. `System` | `Preferences` | `Keyboard` | `Layouts` | `Layout Options...` | `Key to choose 3rd level`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Keyboard Shortcuts under the Preferences menu?